# how to manage session in Azure AD openId authentication in asp.net core app

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I have ASP.NET core application where on front-end I am using React and there are Web APIs to work with the front-end.
I have Azure AD open id connect authentication implemented.

I have a requirement where I need to set session idle timeout after this time the application should get logoff from sign-in session and redirect for login.

Is this possible? if so then please let me know how

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a [token expire policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/configure-token-lifetimes#create-a-policy-for-web-sign-in) for your azure ad app which used to achieve oidc flow.

I've tried the policy, `$policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"TokenLifetimePolicy":{"Version":1,"AccessTokenLifetime":"00:10:00","MaxAgeSessionSingleFactor":"00:10:00"}}') -DisplayName "TinyWebPolicy0401" -IsOrganizationDefault $false -Type "TokenLifetimePolicy"`

and when I press F5 in the browser on my test app website, it will return to the error page because of the id token has expired. Then I need to sign in again.
[image]
[image]